# Set Jupyter R kernel to environment version, not to system default

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, bioconductor

Today I'm setting up an R environment in Anaconda on my Linux machine.  The goal is to run a specfic version of R that can handle the dependencies of a bioinformatics pipeline.

So far, I have: 
downloaded and installed Anaconda (v 4.5.4), and created and activated an environment for R:

```
conda create --name r_3.5.1
conda activate r_3.5.1
```

Searched for and downloaded a specific version of R and R-essentials in the activated environment:

```
conda search r-base
conda install -c conda-forge r=3.5.1
conda search r-essentials
conda install -c r r-essentials=3.5.1
```

However, when I open a `jupyter-notebook` while in this environment, start a new R notebook, and check the `version`, I'm running version 3.2.3.  This old version appears to be what's in my `/usr/bin/r`, while the R version I want is in `/home/me/anaconda3/envs/r_3.5.1`

How can I specify that when I open or create a jupyter-notebook for R in a particular environment, that it opens with the specific version of R I want?

Comment: Did you install `r-irkernel`? Where is `jupyter` installed?

Comment: @merv `jupyter` is installed in `/home/me/anaconda3/envs/r_3.5.1/bin` and  `r-irkernel` is installed  in `/home/me/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir`

Comment: The Conda env must have `r-irkernel` installed as prerequisite for it to be used as a kernel.  Since Jupyter is installed *outside* the env, follow [the instructions on the IRKernel page](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel#installation), which will register the kernel, and then allow you to run `jupyter notebook --kernel your_kernel_name`. I don't run R kernels myself, but I know the ipykernel system fairly well and it has a similar pattern.

Comment: Sorry, `jupyter notebook --kernel your_kernel_name` doesn't make sense, but you can use it for `jupyter console`. The kernel should also appear in the dropdown options when in the jupyter notebook server. Not sure on setting it as the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a Jupyter notebook in the environment was not sufficient to begin using the specified version of R.

To fix the problem, I installed jupyter while in my environment:

```
conda install jupyter
```

Then I opened a prexisting jupyter notebook that had previously been using the wrong R kernel, and ran in a cell:

```
install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()
```

and confirmed with `version` in a different cell that I was running the correct version.

Comment: This is one of my favorite answers on StackOverflow!